# enhancing php script performance

Tags: javascript, php, web, html

(subject of this ques might not match with the ques, but i couldn't think of better) I have a webpage, where user provides email address of recipients, there can be 100 and more email addresses delimited by ; provided.in the textarea. Ofcourse i have to send an email to all those addresses. I have 2 approches in mind but couldn't decide on which one would provide better user experience and performance.
approach 1: i loop through all those emails in my js and send ajax request to php script. But then there would be 100 requests to the server, and if user closes browser in between, all email address wont go through

approach 2: i send all the 100 email addresses in one go to the php script, and let php script loop through emails. I am assuming that i would be able to echo some mesg back to client with success message after each loop count, and even if client is dead, then also at least php will keep executing untill loop ends

can somebody pls provide me cons and pros of these 2 approaches

Comment: No good can come from such a script.

Comment: You need to implement a FIFO queue, that is execute outside of your webapp.

Comment: @john not sure where did you found that I am proposing any solution, i wanted to implement something, and 2 ideas came into my head and I asked for cons and pros, if you had better idea, you must present it here, rather bluntly saying that this is not good

Comment: @john and may be my ideas are not good and may be that is because i have never implemented and created a webapp to do this work, so you suggest some better, liek RPM did and i now understand how it works

Comment: @Tarun - It is my prerogative to give you a good answer, not your right to receive one.  I believe that the script you describe is either inherently evil or so easily co-opted as such that I choose not to provide you with any of a dozen solutions that *would* work.  If I was alone in this opinion, your question would not be so negatively voted. In fact, I think ill of RPM for providing you with an answer at all.

Comment: @john haha, I didnt knew that people like you are also there on Stackoverflow. I dont mind if my question is getting downvoted, it means my question didnt deserved to be here on stackoverflow portal. I completely understand that. You should have also stopped by just downvoting it. It doesnt makes sense at all for you-type of guys to criticize someone's question. It clearly shows how much BAD person you are.  If you dont want to provide me any soln then sit tight and die with it, dont tell me that you dont want to disclose your secret recipe coz quite frankly I dont care abt your opinion.

Comment: @Tarun I think you've got it backwards. StackOverflow is about people contributing back to the world for the greater good... this is the core tenet about why it works. I have several thousand points from helping hundreds of people over the years, which I do because I'm here to help. When presented with a dilemma about somebody doing something building a SPAM engine and bringing net-negative into the world, then yes... you are the one who is counter to the purpose of StackOverflow. Hence the downvotes and the general apathy to your question. You may not realize it, but you're the bad guy here.

Comment: @JohnGreen You gotta be kidding me -  "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions" Thats the way stackoverflow works. Thats it, I am done. Sorry If I have offended you by any means by asking the above ques, coz it clearly looks like it has deeply hurt your sentiments :P

Comment: You clearly don't understand why it works.  Your loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea on how to implement a queue.

```
define('MAX_EMAIL_BUFFER_SIZE', 15);

// do a query to see how many emails are needed to be sent, you need to do store
// this data in mysql or some other place.
// array getEmails() { }

$total = count( getEmails());
$pages = ceil($total / MAX_EMAIL_BUFFER_SIZE);
$i = 0;
for(; $i < $total; $i++) {
  $offset = ($page - 1)  * MAX_EMAIL_BUFFER_SIZE;
    /* query
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        table
    ORDER BY
        name
    LIMIT
        MAX_EMAIL_BUFFER_SIZE
    OFFSET
        $offset
   */
  // the result returned by the query are the emails you wills send.
  // do the above query in a function that returns the results

  foreach($data as $email) {
    mail(...);
  }
  // sleep for 10 seconds.
  sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand, you are suggesting, that in my DB there would be a table which will contain email IDs to whom emails needs to be sent, and some external queue will read that DB table and will send the email

Comment: I like this idea. Though I need to now see how to create external script, may be some kind of cron job can be scheduled or it has to be manual